# Pyright LSP flagging errors in class using pandas method

Tags: neovim, python, lsp

Using the following code example:

```python
import pandas as pd
from typing import Dict


class Test:
    def __init__(self, df : pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.df = df

    def example(self, replacements : Dict[str, str]) -> None:
        self.df = self.df.rename(columns = replacements)
```

Nvim displays:

[image]

`rename` is definitely a member of a dataframe object, and Pyright is aware of the venv I'm using as I get pandas completion:

[image]

I even get completion of the member which is an "error"

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly to check / post to make things clearer as I'm only recently setting this up.

I think the question is basically - how do I get the LSP to recognise that this is a "known" member? I'm not sure how it determines that, I'd like to be able to use pandas without so many errors though.

### "Which plugin do you have installed?"

These are the plugins that I have installed:

```
    use "wbthomason/packer.nvim" -- have packer manage itself
    use "nvim-lua/popup.nvim" -- implementation of the popup api from vim in nvim
    use "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" -- useful lua functions
    use "windwp/nvim-autopairs" -- integrates with other stuff.... autocmp and whatever
    use "kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons"
    use "kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua"
    use "lunarvim/colorschemes"
    use "folke/tokyonight.nvim"
    use "tanvirtin/monokai.nvim"
    use "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp" -- completion plugin
    use "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer" -- buffer completions
    use "hrsh7th/cmp-path" -- path completions
    use "hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline" -- cmdline completions
    use "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua" -- cmdline completions
    use "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp" -- lsp completions
    use "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip" -- snippet completions completions
    use "L3MON4D3/Luasnip" -- snippet engine
    use "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets" -- snippet engine
    use "neovim/nvim-lspconfig" -- enable lsp
    use "williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer" -- simple to use language server installer
    use "jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim" -- for formatters and linters
    use "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim"
    use 'nvim-telescope/telescope-media-files.nvim'
    use "lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim"
```

### "What is the lsp configuration?"

```lua
-- Following: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#Suggested-configuration

-- See `:help vim.diagnostic.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }
-- NOTE: Not sure about these atm
-- vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>e', vim.diagnostic.open_float, opts)
-- vim.keymap.set('n', '[d', vim.diagnostic.goto_prev, opts)
-- vim.keymap.set('n', ']d', vim.diagnostic.goto_next, opts)
-- vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>q', vim.diagnostic.setloclist, opts)

-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')

  -- Mappings.
  -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
  local bufopts = { noremap=true, silent=true, buffer=bufnr }
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-k>', vim.lsp.buf.signature_help, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wa', vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wr', vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wl', function()
    print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))
  end, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>D', vim.lsp.buf.type_definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gr', vim.lsp.buf.references, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>f', vim.lsp.buf.formatting, bufopts)
end


local lsp_flags = {
  -- This is the default in Nvim 0.7+
  debounce_text_changes = 150,
}

require('lspconfig')['pyright'].setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = lsp_flags,
}
```

Comment: Can tell us which plugin you have installed? e.g. It could be that pyright knows panda but ALE do not.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt thanks - i updated the post with the plugins that are installed.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe  could you try to reproduce the problem only with the lsp plugin to be sure the completion plugin doesn't interfere. I see no reference to pyright. Is pyright part of the configuration of lsp? What is the lsp configuration?

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt thanks, updated the OP

Comment: I just started using Lunarvim and am running into a similar issue. I'm new to typing in Python which makes it even more confusinger.

Did you ever resolve this issue?